# Наречия в роли частиц

Tags: наречия, частицы

Заметил, что многие наречия выполняют роли частиц на самом деле.

Возьмем например частицу [буквально](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE)

```
в знач. частицы действительно, на самом деле, прямо-таки ◆ Часть реки была буквально усыпана народом.
```

Но это ведь ничем не отличается от наречий *фактически, практически, реально*

```
Часть реки была фактически/практически/реально усыпана народом.
```

Значит ли это, что в данном предложении все эти наречия являются на самом деле частицами?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не значит.

Если понять "усыпана народом" буквально, то, как бы это ни звучало, например, какой-то великан взял и усыпал часть реки людьми. А здесь не значение "буквально", здесь значение "прямо", а это как раз тоже частица, может, этим и руководствовались составители словаря.

1) Такое образное выражение фактом не назвать;
2) *практически* — это "почти", далеко по смыслу;
3) *реально* — тоже, про такое образное так не скажут, или это про тех, кто слово "типа" вставляет куда попало.

Частица используется для усиления смысла, типа "представьте себе, даже так", у этих трёх слов нет такого. Важно то, что если частица, то меняется смысл, и он становится не особо существенным, иногда даже его и описать трудно. В том же смысле оно частицей не будет. Выше указано изменение смысла данного слова.

Answer (score -1):

Слово ‟буквально” является вводным характера подачи, как: ‟одним слово”, ‟короче говоря”, ‟иначе говоря”, ‟вернее”, ‟точнее”, ‟проще сказать”. Так как последующая часть предложения может показаться невероятной и собеседник сочтет это фигуральной речью, говорящий использует вводное ‟буквально” (сокращение от ‟буквально говоря”), дабы предотвратить такое восприятие.  Этим словом говорящий обозначает то, что далее последует не фигуральная, а буквальная речь. Зачастую употребяется неосмысленно и после этого слова всё же следует фигуральная, а не буквальная речь. Конечно, как и все вводные, может употребляться как член предложения. Вот пример такого предложения: ‟Не следует воспринимать эти слова буквально”.

Comment: "Буквально" вводным не является.

Comment: Спасибо за мнение.

Comment: Но это не мнение, а факт. Оно нигде не обособляется как вводное.

Comment: https://pishugramotno.ru/punktuacia/bukvalno-vydelyaetsya-zapyatymi-ili-net

Comment: Я знаю, что оно нигде не классифицируется как вводное и не обособляется как вводное

Comment: Ага, то есть вы решили идти против системы...

Comment: Что есть, то есть